# Rails, concatenating 2 variables and display them in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, concatenation

thanks in advance for your help! 
I would like to concatenate 2 variables and display both in one cell in table in the view. More specifically I want to display column "game score" e.g. 5:7 by concatenating @game.team1_score and @game.team2_score.
Can you help out with this one line?

```
 <% @games.each do |game| %><tbody>
<tr>
  <td><%= game.id %> </td>
  <td><%= game.team1 %></td>
  <td><%= game.team2 %></td>
  <td><%= game.team1_score ":" game.team2_score %></td>
  <td><%= game.updated_at %></td>
  <td><%=link_to("Detail", game_path(game.id), class: 'action show') %></td>
  <td><%=link_to("Edit", edit_game_path(game.id), class: 'action edit') %></td>
  <td><%=link_to("Delete", game_path(game.id), method: :delete, class: 'action delete') %> <br></td>
  <% end %>
</tr>
```

Comment: yes, syntax error on line 6

Comment: it works :) ..thank you @m2j!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this!

`<td><%= game.team1_score %>:<%= game.team2_score %></td>`